# How can I style an HTML element to avoid hanging text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a page where there's a textbox that displays a text string from the database, and its length varies.  Because of this, some strings happen to be long enough to run onto two lines, but that second line is short, and this doesn't look good:

[image]

Here the blue box shows the `div` that contains the content.  It's got a fixed width (80% of the container), and `text-align:center`.

So my question is: how can I get the text to flow into lines where the line widths are closer to each other? I'm willing to do some math and dynamically adjust the width or font size, but I'm not sure how to do this reliably.

Comment: If you do not need the text to wrap at all you could use `white-space:nowrap` style

Comment: @PatrickEvans that'll cause overflow..

Comment: @Joshua what do you mean by "line widths are closer to each other" ??

Comment: @Joshua - does the blue div need to be the fixed 80%? Or, would it be okay to increase its width to get just the 'Falls!' word on the same line as the others?

Comment: @TilwinJoy: I mean that there's shouldn't be one line much shorter than the other.

Comment: @dgp: No, I can adjust the container width to fit everything on one line, or to force two lines of more equal width.  I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Run it through a JavaScript function using .split() and divide by two. Not a perfect solution but should split the sentence up a little better.

Answer (score 3):

You need JavaScript to do this. CSS alone cannot fix this issue if you are using dynamic text.

Once you've detected that the height of the box goes beyond the limit of one line you can either shrink the font, expand the box or calculate the mid-point to add a break and have two balanced lines.

Here are various jQuery plugins that an do this for you. There are many if you look.

http://fittextjs.com/

https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill

Answer (score -1):

personally I don't like use javascript to "simple things"

you use the following properties

```
overflow 
white-space
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALWqd/